# SVG lengthAdjust only for shrinking but not for stretching

Tags: svg, text, resize

Is there a nice and easy way to to have the functionality of [lengthAdjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/lengthAdjust) (together with [textLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength)) for shrinking text if necessary (if too wide) but never attempting to stretch it?

Two possible solutions for a SVG generated through JS come to my mind:

- Count characters (or rather *grapheme clusters*) and based on that (together with some heuristics unless a fixed-width size font is used) determine whether to set `textLength` or not.
- First do it without `textLength` set and then determine using `getBBox()` whether the text needs some shrinking in which case `textLength` will be set.

Both solutions are IMHO quite ugly (and possibly buggy from my recollections of past encounters with `getBBox()`). Is there maybe some nicer solution I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886640/1925631
Essentially, make a path which spans the exact coordinates where you want to spread your text on a path. Measure this path. Then, measure how many pixels your text requires, with a font-size of 1px (and other desired font-features). Now adjust the font-size to fill your desired percentage of the available path advance width. Adjust start-offset and text-anchor. Now finally calculate your author specified textLength and choose a lengthAdjust value to get exact alignment on low precision / non-conformant renderers.

Finally, if you need to support viewers without text on a path rendering support, you can use a conformant viewer with javascript support to create a backwards compatible/fallback version. Render the content and use the SVG DOM api to fetch the x, y and rotate values for each character/glyph, now create a new SVG DOM representation with those attributes specified. You might need javascript to calculate absolute width and height for the root svg element as well, and a correctly specified viewBox, and cascade/resolve/convert all css selectors/rules/properties to inline attributes. But this way you can get cross-platform, cross-browser/viewer rendering of text, with a single compilation step per immutable source file version.

I've also made a gist to ease the last step, of resolving the css and removing all classNames, while preserving the rendered end-result: https://gist.github.com/msand/4b37d3ce04246f83cb28fdbfe4716ecc

This is for the purpose of a single universal svg + javascript codebase, and web+ios+android software development (based on react + react-native + react-native-svg)

Comment: Some issues with getComputedTextLength in various browsers, and the importance of choosing an appropriate conformant viewer, to calculate per character / glyph position values based on the common subset of available svg / font features in the required viewers:
https://bl.ocks.org/MSCAU/58bba77cdcae42fc2f44

Comment: A collection of relevant runnable tests/animations/visualisations: https://codepen.io/jovdb/full/egXVxo

Comment: Complexities of calculating font metrics related aspects such as font-size/line-height/text-bounds: 
 http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/ and another beautiful one about how the all the properties and font data/metrics interact, and how vertical-alignment affects the line-height, content-area, virtual-area, line-box and thus the various bounds metrics and lengths: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: One might have to keep in mind that `getComputedTextLength` is independent of the stroke (and therefore any `stroke-width` value).